# DB Schema version not supported

Tags: database

I am migrating my databases to my new server and encounter this error when trying to attach. "This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm."

How do I go about migrating the DB's if I am getting this error.[image]

Comment: Which SharePoint version is configured in new server? Also mention the CUs you have installed on the server?

Comment: Ive gone from 2013 to 2016

Comment: SharePoint 2013 server should be SP1 or higher version. This link may help you.: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263026%28v=office.16%29.aspx

Comment: Have you tried to run Farm configuration wizard after DB attachment?

Comment: @DikeshGandhi Never ever use the Farm Configuration Wizard. You need to configure service applications manually to control the process in good fashion. "For instance, running the Farm Configuration Wizard will create a series of content and service application databases. It is unlikely that the names of these databases will meet the naming convention requirements
in your organization because SharePoint uses default database names that include a globally unique identifier (GUID) suffix." #Exam 70-339 book ref

Comment: Apology....I was asking about SharePoint Product configuration wizard. Thanks @BennySkogberg for correction.

Answer (score 1):

At first you run [Test-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607941.aspx) to see if you're missing fetures or site definitions. If you do, you need to install the solutions and site definitions that are missing.

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -name "WSS_Content" -webapplication http://sitename -ServerInstance "SQL2"
```

When you have a successful run of Test-SPContentDatabase, you run [Upgrade-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813.aspx), which will migrate the database schema of your content database to the 2016 farm schema.

```
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content
```

When your database is upgraded, mount it using the cmdlet [Mount-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the build number of your `destination farm` is not identical (lower) to the build number of the source farm.

So to solve this issue,before you take a backup of content database from source farm , you should match the `Configuration database version` of destination farm to be the same as the source farm by following the mentioned steps below:

- Get the `build number` of your source and destination farm ,
- Check which farm has a higher build number , and install it to the lower build number farm.
- Now make sure that the build number at the source and destination farm is identical.
- Get a backup from source , attach it to the destination ,  mount it to the destination . via PowerShell

> ```
> Mount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentDb>" -DatabaseServer "<DbServer>" -WebApplication http://SiteName
> ```

I wrote about this issue in more details at [This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/05/this-content-database-has-a-schema-version-which-is-not-supported-in-this-farm/)